# Getting this error: ProgrammingError at /admin/ relation "myapp_myuser" does not exist while creating superuser or going on localhost/admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I tried extending the user model in django with the help of django docs.I wanted to add a mobile field to it.I did everything and then even executed makemigrations , sqlmigrate and migrate and got no error but when i try to execute python manage.py createsuperuser i get a response asking for email and as soon as it enter email i get this error

I havent made a separate app for this model and am using the same models.py for the whole project
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 249, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 220, in inner
    if not self.has_permission(request):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 194, in has_permission
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 224, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 360, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 180, in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 161, in get_user
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\ myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation " myapp_myuser" does not exist
LINE 1: ...er"."is_active", " myapp_myuser"."is_admin" FROM " myapp_m...
```

Here is my code:
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, mobile, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not mobile:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a mobile number')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            mobile=mobile,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, mobile, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            mobile=mobile,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email




    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import Category,Product,MyUser
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField



class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'mobile')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'mobile', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'mobile', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('mobile',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'mobile', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()



admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(Group)

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

**Please tell me how to solve the error.**

Comment: Should i add it in postgres directly and should i also add the fields that it has like email mobile password and all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you remove all of the `*.py` files from `migrations` except the `__init__.py`.
Then have clean database and run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.

Just be sure `__init__.py` file exists inside the `migrations` package.

If it still didn't work, please add the output of those two commands to your question.

Comment: How do i have a clean database?I am using postgres

Comment: I suggest `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE`. please search for more detailed answers on this.

Comment: YEPP.. I had been trying to figure out how to solve my probelm for week and dropping and creating a new database finally worked......Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking the answer   as the correct one.

Comment: Done!! It would be helpful for others if you edit your answer and put the drop and create database part in it coz that worked for me and this solution on my check wasnt available anywhere.

Comment: This is not a fix. This is erasing your issues and starting fresh.